# How to encapsulate ansible filters?

Tags: filter, ansible

I have an ansible variable that contains a list of `win_uri` responses (created by `loop`).

I want to create a dictionary where each single response body (json) contains a value (title) that I want to use as a key and another one as a value (id).

Right now I am lost.

My current implementation ignores the json - which obviously does not work:

```
- name: populate folder dictionary
  set_fact:
    app_folders: "{{ app_folders | default({}) | combine({item.jsonContent.title : item.id}) }}"
  with_items: "{{ response.results }}"
```

I know, that it is possible to read JSON into a variable with the `from_json` - but I do not know how to combine it with the above code.

Comment: perhaps template module would be helpful here. template is based on the jinja2 module of python and supports loop as well. so you can create a jinja2 template apply a for loop with on the response. You can share the response I can write a jinja2 based on that

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, try:

```
- name: populate folder dictionary
  set_fact:
    app_folders: "{{ app_folders | default({}) | combine({(item.jsonContent|from_json).title : item.id}) }}"
  with_items: "{{ response.results }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I already learned more about ansible and I am currently using the `json_query` - but yes, itt seems as if this could have solved my problem!